# Whatsapp-Web.js restore session

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

I'm using the whatsapp-web.js library and I would like to stay logged in after restarting the script. Currently I have to scan the QR code every time I start. The things I found online couldn't get to work (probably cuz I'm dumb but still). For reference this is the code I am trying to get it working with.

```
const { Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const fs = require('fs');



const client = new Client({
    ffmpegPath: "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"
});



client.on('qr', async qr=> {
     qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});

});

client.on('ready', async function () {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. For anyone who sees this and has the same issue, this is what worked for me: add this to the client: `authStrategy: new LocalAuth()` and after generating the qr code for the first time, wait a couple of minutes before hitting ctrl+c

Comment: hi, I am using `const client = new Client({ authStrategy: new LocalAuth({ clientId: "1234" }) });` but on `authenticated` my `session` object (`JSON.stringify(session)`) is always `undefined` is always undefined, any idea why?

Comment: @yeln me too. Did you find a solution? I'm getting `undefined` session as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, LegacySessionAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');

// Path where the session data will be stored
const SESSION_FILE_PATH = './session.json';

// Load the session data if it has been previously saved
let sessionData;
if(fs.existsSync(SESSION_FILE_PATH)) {
    sessionData = require(SESSION_FILE_PATH);
}

// Use the saved values
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LegacySessionAuth({
        session: sessionData
    })
});

// Save session values to the file upon successful auth
client.on('authenticated', (session) => {
    sessionData = session;
    fs.writeFile(SESSION_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(session), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi,
"LegacySessionAuth" doesn't work with MultiDevice...

Answer (score -1):

In recent versions, you have to manually implement `LocalAuth`.

To do this open the "**Client.js**" file located at
"**./node_modules/whatssap-web.js/src/Client.js**" and implement this line

```
const LocalAuth = require('./authStrategies/LocalAuth');
```

and now change the line #68

```
this.authStrategy = new NoAuth();
```

to

```
this.authStrategy = new LocalAuth();
```

for version 1.16.4-alpha.0
date: 27/08/2022